# Does Objective-C feature runtime methods for Protocol message forwarding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols

I am using Protocols very often like this:

```
@protocol AnotherObjectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)someMethodWithObject:(id)object;
@end
@interface AnotherObject : NSObject
@property (assign) id<AnotherObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

My BaseObject does conform to that protocol and is also the delegate which receives the messages coming from AnotherObject.

```
@interface BaseObject : NSObject <AnotherObjectDelegate>
@property AnotherObject* anotherObject;
@property SecondLevelObject* secondLevelObject;
@end

@implementation BaseObject
-(instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.anotherObject = [AnotherObject new];
        self.anotherObject.delegate = self;
    }
}
-(void)someMethodWithObject:(id)object {
    // Forwarding Message from Delegate to other Object conforming to protocol:
    [self.secondLevelObject someMethodWithObject:object];
}
@end
```

The BaseObject-Instance however acts as some kind of Proxy for other instances to forward the protocol-messages to other object which are owned by object after the BaseObject:

```
@interface SecondLevelObject : NSObject <AnotherObjectDelegate>
@property ThirdLevelObject* thirdLevelObject;
@end

@implementation SecondLevelObject
-(void)someMethodWithObject:(id)object {
    [self.thirdLevelObject someMethodWithObject:object];
}
@end
```

In the SecondLevelObject there is a ThirdLevelObject which also does conform to the same protocol. And here I also forward the message - so the SecondLevelObjects also acts as some kind of proxy.

```
@interface ThirdLevelObject : NSObject <AnotherObjectDelegate>
@end

@implementation ThirdLevelObject
-(void)someMethodWithObject:(id)object {
    // Finally it's here
}
@end
```

I am using this kind of class-design in order to prevent using long pointer-chains like:

```
anotherObject.delegate = baseObject.secondLevelObject.thirdLevelObject;
```

and to prevent my classes from having to much weak/assign-references which can be hard to debug when you have multiple objects conforming to multiple protocols.

One of the downsides is that I have to add those boilerplate-code-like protocol-implementations in every class which is being used as a "proxy" to forward the messages. Even if - in my case - this is easier to read and debug.

So I was asking myself if there would be an easier way of doing this. I also did this in that way to prevent my code from calling

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]
    [delegate someMethod];
```

Is there some kind of Objective-C runtime function that can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to implement `forwardingTargetForSelector:`. When you receive messages you don't respond to, this method will be called, and whatever object it returns will be sent the message.

For example:

```
@implementation SecondLevelObject
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    // Often you would actually check the selector here
    return self.thirdLevelObject;
}
@end
```

The problem is that now `SecondLevelObject` doesn't appear to conform to the protocol, and that will generate warnings. You can suppress that warning (since you really do conform to the protocol) using a pragma:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
@implementation SecondLevelObject
...
@end
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

This turns off the protocol-checking for the whole object, though, so you need to be very careful with it. In most cases I find it much easier and clearer to just write the forwarding code. If there's a lot of it, it sometimes indicates a different design problem. Perhaps LevelThreeObject should really be the delegate itself, or maybe looser systems like notifications or KVO would have been better. But forwarding does still come up quite legitimately, and this is one technique to consider.

Comment: I've tested different design but forwarding seems to be most transparent and most performant since I am often forwarding methods which are being called multiples times a second. I wasn't pretty sure that forwarding is a common thing but now I am! Thank you!